# Replaying Yogg-Saron

Tags: hearthstone

Yogg-Saron reads:

[image]

> Cast a random spell for each spell you've cast this game (*targets chosen randomly*).

My question is: Let's say I've cast 10 spells this game. I now play Yogg-Saron, and he will cast 10 spells for me. The last spell he casts is a Shadowstep/Vanish (something that returns him to my hand).

If I play him next turn, how many spells will he cast for me? Still **10** (because I as a player did not cast any more), or **20** (because Yogg reads '*cast*')?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yogg-Saron counts only the spells cast by the player for its battlecry. Spells played by a previous activation of Yogg-Saron are considered cast by Yogg itself, so they don't add to the total (as you can read in [this official tweet](https://twitter.com/PlayHearthstone/status/718128518396248065)).

So, in your example, the second Yogg will cast only 10 spells.

Comment: The [Wiki article for Yogg-Saron](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Yogg-Saron,_Hope%27s_End#Notes) goes into detail on this, too.

Comment: The spell-ownership effect seems pretty similar to druid minions with a choose-one effect ([Mire Keeper](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/33162-mire-keeper) or [Ancient of Lore](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/34-ancient-of-lore): the player who summoned the minion gets the positive effect (mana crystal; card draw), but it doesn't count as a spell cast by the player – the ancillary effects for cards like that are [spell cards](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/517-ancient-teachings) (though uncollectible, so they can't be discovered or replayed by Yogg).